# what's the best practice for testing deleting a directory?

Tags: go, testing

I have a cli that I am making that is more for learning purposes and creating my own cli, that does stuff. Anyways, I am testing the `delete` function and it works fine and gives me the right answer. However, I don't believe that it is the best practice and was wondering if you could let me know if it's ok, or not.

#### Test file

```golang
func TestDeleteConfig(t *testing.T) {
    err := cm.DeleteConfig()
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error when deleting the folder: %s", err)
    }

    usr, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error when getting user current: %s", err)
    }

    fp := filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".config", "godot", "config.json")
    fmt.Println("the path of the config file", fp)

    if _, e := os.Stat(fp); !os.IsNotExist(e) {
        t.Errorf("error path still exists: %v", e)
    }
}
```

#### function being tested

```golang
func DeleteConfig() error {

    usr, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = os.RemoveAll(filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".config", "godot"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The problem is that I don't want the `DeleteConfig()` to take any arguments as this is a hard path. I have a separate function for deleting a single file in which the help with this will solve that as well `func DeleteFile(p string) error {}`.

So for testing purposes should I just create a `foo` directory at a separate path (within the test), delete said directory, and assume that if it works on `foo` path then it should work with the `godot` directory?

Comment: What is the reason to test that os.RemoveAll actually works? Do you think the stdlib is broken? What actual problem/issue are you trying to solve with this test? And what is is "a hard path"? What would be wrong with an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit philosophical.

If you absolutely do not want to stub/mock any part of your code to replace accessing a real file system to do testing, then we're talking about what you'd call system or integration testing. That's fine in itself: for instance, you could run such tests in a throw-away container as part of a CI pipeline.

But with this approach you can't sensibly do what is called unit-testing.

To unit-test your function you need to replace *something* it uses with something "virtualized". Exactly how to do that is an open question.

#### Approach: make is possible to override `os.RemoveAll`

For instance, you can have a private global variable containing the "remove whole directory" function—like this:

```golang
var removeAll = os.RemoveAll

func DeleteConfig() error {

    usr, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = removeAll(filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".config", "godot"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Then to test it you'd just monkey-patch the function with your own implementation which would have the same signature as `os.RemoveAll`, like this:

```golang
func TestDeleteConfig(t *testing.T) {
  var actualPath string

  removeAll = func(path string) {
    actualPath = path
    return nil
  }
  defer func() { removeAll = os.RemoveAll }()

  DeleteConfig()

  if actualPath != expectedPath {
    t.Errorf("unexpected path: want %s, got %s", expectedPath, actualPath)
  }
}
```

This approach also allows to test how your function handles errors: just replace it with something which generates an error and then afterwards check that your function under test returned that error (or wrapped it in an expected way, whatever).

Still, it's a bit low-tech for a number of reasons:

- A global variable is involved, so you have to be sure no two tests which monkey-patch it run concurrently, or that all patching is done before running those tests.
- If different tests need to set it to different value, they must be serialized.

#### Approach: do not hard-code the concept of "the user" or "the config"

Another approach is to notice that basically the problem with testing stems from the fact you hard-coded getting of the user.

Leaving aside the flawed approach you've taken to getting the place of configuration (you should be using [something which implements the XDG spec](https://www.google.com/?q=golang+xdg)), if you could easily override getting of the "root" directory (which is the user's home directory in your code), you could easily target your function to operate on the result of calling [`io/ioutil.TempDir`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempDir).

So may be a way to go is to have an interface type like

```golang
type ConfigStore interface {
  Dir() string
}
```

of which the `Dir()` method is supposed to return the path to the configuration store's root directory.

Your `DeleteConfig()` would then start to accept a single argument of type `ConfigStore`, and in your program you'd have a concrete implementation of it, and in your testing code — a stub implementing the same interface and managing a temporary directory.

#### Approach: go full-on virtualized

Right now, a work is being done on [bringing filesystem virtualization right into the Go standard library](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-iofs.md), but while it's not there yet, 3rd-party packages which do that exist for ages, — for instance, [`github.com/spf13/afero`](https://github.com/spf13/afero).

Basically, they allow you to not use `os` directly but write all your code in a way so that instead of the `os` package it calls methods on an instance of a type implementing particular interface: in the production code that object is a thin shim for the `os` package, and in the testing code it's replaced by whatever you wish; `afero` has a readily-available in-memory FS backend [to do this](https://github.com/spf13/afero#using-afero-for-testing).

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for all this information. A lot to go over!

Comment: Code that's difficult to test can indicate inflexibility in the design. I try to make the code more flexible before looking to mocking or virtualization. Having a ConfigStore allows the user to decide where their configuration is stored: a feature! And instead of passing a ConfigStore into DeleteConfig, consider making Delete, and anything else that works with the configuration, a method of ConfigStore. `func (config ConfigStore) Delete() error`. Then you can expand on `ConfigStore` and unit test it.

Comment: The thought process was that if I create the `config.json` was thet when deleting it I'll know where to find it rather than search. But, thanks for the input. I guess that would be a lot simpler of an option

Comment: @Schwern, good idea but I tried to display an approach to analysis of the problem at hand. With your proposal, which I find good, you're back to square one as `ConfigStore.Delete` depends on the internals of the concrete type satisfying `ConfigStore`—I mean, if you have, say, a `ConfigStore` impl. based on using a real FS, you cannot test how its `Delete` method works _in isolation._ Of course it's still possible to test the whole thing—provided one is able to somehow reliably influence where the data is located on the FS so that the testing setup code could do that.

Comment: @kostix Yes, I am assuming the concrete implementation of ConfigStore allows the return value of `Dir()` to be changed to point at a temp directory. Otherwise you're just pushing the inflexibility down a level.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a unit test for filesystem checking is not trivial. You should NOT create a real file on the system, because then your test will depend on the I/O of the file system itself. The last resort is mocking the filesystem. There are quite a few powerful libraries like spf13/afero for this purpose (mocking of a filesystem). These packages will create temporary files in the background and clean up afterward.

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/user"
    "path/filepath"

    iowrap "github.com/spf13/afero"
)

var (
    // FS is simulated filesystem interface
    FS iowrap.Fs
    // FSUtil is the struct of the simulated interface
    FSUtil *iowrap.Afero
)

func init() {
    FS = iowrap.NewOsFs()
    FSUtil = &iowrap.Afero{Fs: FS}
}

// DeleteConfig removes ~/.config/godot if exists
func DeleteConfig() error {

    usr, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    path := filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".config", "godot")
    log.Println(path)
    err = FSUtil.RemoveAll(path)
    return err
}

func main() {
    err := DeleteConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

main_test.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "os/user"
    "path/filepath"
    "testing"

    iowrap "github.com/spf13/afero"
)

func init() {
    FS = iowrap.NewMemMapFs()
    FSUtil = &iowrap.Afero{Fs: FS}

    usr, _ := user.Current()
    pathDir := filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".config")
    filePath := filepath.Join(pathDir, "godot")
    FS.MkdirAll(pathDir, 0755)
    iowrap.WriteFile(FS, filePath, []byte("0-7\n"), 0644)
}

const (
    succeed = "\u2713"
    failed  = "\u2717"
)

func TestDeleteConfig(t *testing.T) {
    t.Log("Given the need to test downloading a webpage content")
    {
        usr, _ := user.Current()
        pathDir := filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".config")
        filePath := filepath.Join(pathDir, "godot")
        t.Logf("\tTest 0:\tWhen deleting the %v with 0644 permissions", filePath)
        {
            err := DeleteConfig()
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatalf("\t%s\tThe file couldn't be deleted: %v", failed, err)
            }
            t.Logf("\t%s\tThe file has been successfully deleted.", succeed)
        }
    }
}
```

Functional test:

```sh
touch C:/Users/drpan/.config/godot
ls -l C:/Users/drpan/.config/godot     Output: -rw-r--r-- 1 drpan 197609 0 Nov  2 19:38 C:/Users/drpan/.config/godot
./deletedirectory.exe
 ls -l C:/Users/drpan/.config/godot     Output: ls: cannot access 'C:/Users/drpan/.config/godot': No such file or directory
```

Unit Test:

```sh
$ touch C:/Users/drpan/.config/godot
$ go test
2020/11/02 19:55:35 C:\Users\drpan\.config\godot
PASS
ok      github.com/drpaneas/deletedirectory     0.162s

$ ls -l C:/Users/drpan/.config/godot            Output: -rw-r--r-- 1 drpan 197609 0 Nov  2 19:55 C:/Users/drpan/.config/godot
```